# SQL query: How to select record from other table where no record exist or count = 0 (conditional)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

i had two tables:

Table 1: StaffDB

```
SID | Name
1   | Peter
2   | Mary
3   | John
```

Table 2: Employment History (staff will have more than 1 records)

```
HistID | SID | PositionID | isCurrent | StartDate  | EndDate  
1      | 1   | 123        | 0         | dd-mm-yyyy | dd-mm-yyyy  
2      | 1   | 221        | 1         | dd-mm-yyyy |  
3      | 2   | 434        | 0         | dd-mm-yyyy | dd-mm-yyyy
```

For example, in table 2.

```
Peter (SID=1) had 2 records, 2nd record is current record (isCurrent=1)  

Mary (SID=2) had 1 non current record  

John (SID=3) don't have any record
```

How can i write a sql query to select staff who don't have any employment history or don't have any current record (isCurrent=1)

for the above example, should returns Mary and John.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a LEFT JOIN and check for a NULL primary key on the joined table:

```
SELECT StaffDB.*
FROM StaffDB
LEFT JOIN EmploymentHistory ON StaffDB.SID = EmploymentHistory.SID
  AND EmploymentHistory.isCurrent = 1
WHERE EmploymentHistory.HistID IS NULL
```

Or use EXISTS - this will possibly be more performant, although not as easily readable (subjective):

```
SELECT *
FROM StaffDB
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM EmploymentHistory 
                  WHERE EmploymentHistory.SID = StaffDB.SID
                  AND EmploymentHistory.isCurrent = 1)
```